# A foreigner has $11,000 and they are flying to the US. They claim it on FinCen 105. They show the form to the CBP agent. What happens next?

Tags: banking, wire-transfer, travel, family, customs

A foreigner has $11,000 and they are flying to the US. 
They claim it on FinCen 105 and the CBP Form 6059-B. They show the forms to the CBP agent. 
What happens next?

The purpose is a long family vacation(4 months) 2 US citizens (husband and son) and 1 Chinese citizen (wife).

I am aware that money divided among the 3 people totaling 10,000 or more still requires the same FinCen 105 for. I am also aware that it is expected that tourists are able to prove that the have enough money to support themselves upon arrival. All three of us do not have a US bank account to wire money.

A follow up question for the comments - Are their anyways to make an account while abroad before flying so that some of the funds can be wired to the US account in advance?

Comment: Do they have access to a credit card/debit card that will work in the US?

Comment: What country do you live in?  As @mhoran_psprep suggests you might be better off seeking out Visa/MasterCard credit/debit cards with low (or zero) fees for foreign purchases and withdrawals.  E.g. in the UK there are several such products to choose from (see http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/travel/overseas-card-charges) which generally work out much cheaper than converting currency to foreign cash at a bank or bureau de change.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no problems with CBP; they'll take the form and may ask some questions, but it is completely legal.

I would be worried to carry so much cash around though, and many places might not readily accept cash. You cannot rent a car (without a huge cash deposit), and you cannot book hotels or anything else online with the cash. If you have any way to have a credit card, prefer that. If this is not possible consider even buying a refillable card in a supermarket after arrival.

Comment: We plan to open a bank account as soon as we arrive. But, we have not figured out how to do it before hand.

Comment: You might not be able to. American banks are picking their customers according to Credit Scores, and as you don't live here, you don't have one, so they will not make you an account. Be prepared for that.

Comment: Does that include local credit unions?

Comment: Actually I pulled my 3 scores with Identiguard.com recently they are between 640 and 700. Do you know of any ways to open new credit while abroad? I do have a mailing address and someone I trust to collect it.

Comment: @JeffreyRust That is a (worthwhile) question on its own; it would be best if you asked it separately.